# Android : Does viewmodelscope cancel all jobs on detach from window of fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, coroutinescope

I want to know if oncleared of viewmodel is called when onDetach of a fragment is called. This is to make sure that all coroutines will be cancelled. I was getting a IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to a context before refactoring to kotlin and coroutines. Now I am using viemodelscope to do these tasks.

Comment: you must be doing something related with context, that's causing the issue, but that context is not alive anymore

Comment: yeah, I am doing getResources but what I want to be sure that using coroutines with viewmodelscope will take care of this. If scope is ended onDetach then these task will not be executed.

Comment: No you should check whether context is still null or not

Answer (score 1):

As Google notes on the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel):

> Figure 1 illustrates the various lifecycle states of an activity as it
>   undergoes a rotation and then is finished. The illustration also shows
>   the lifetime of the ViewModel next to the associated activity
>   lifecycle. This particular diagram illustrates the states of an
>   activity. **The same basic states apply to the lifecycle of a fragment.**

And this is the image:

[image]

So the answer is: ViewModel's `onCleared` is called when `onDestroy` is called from `Activity`/`Fragment` .

As for your coroutines, you should `cancel()` the job on the `onCleared()`

Comment: If u use viewModelScope, all the jobs will be cancelled whenever onCleared is called.

Comment: Yes, but I was answering your question, I know about the `ViewModelScope`

Answer (score 0):

If any `Context` or UI related logic has to be executed on the result of any asynchronous or API calls, can result in this issue even if `onDetach` is called. You should make safe calls like null checking to get rid of that exception.